# How to avoid R crashing on a call to cor due to standard devation of zero?

Tags: r

For example, If I run:

```
cor(rep(1,7), rep(1,7))
Error in cor(rep(1, 7), rep(1, 7)) :
  (converted from warning) the standard deviation is zero
 1: cor(rep(1, 7), rep(1, 7))
 2: .signalSimpleWarning("the standard deviation is zero", quote(cor(rep(1, 7), rep(1, 7))))
 3: withRestarts({
    .Internal(.signalCondition(simpleWarning(msg, call), msg, call))
    .Internal(.dfltWarn(msg, call))
}, muffleWarning = function() NULL)
 4: withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1]])
 5: doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
```

This is an issue when I try to run an `sapply` on the `names(some.data.frame)` to compute the correlation of each column in two data frames with identically names columns. There are about 80 columns, and one of the columns has a zero vector causing this crash to call, is there a way to avoid this and instead output `NA`?

Comment: Is `trycatch`  all you need?  Either that, or if you're sure the only case of `sd==0` is for a zero vector, remove that vector from your dataframe before starting out.

Comment: off topic: did you know that you can do `cor(some.data.frame, some.another.data.frame)` to compute correlation between columns of two `data.frame`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like you set R to convert all warnings into errors with the options command.

this will set it back:

```
options(warn=0)
```

warn:

sets the handling of warning messages. If warn is negative all warnings are ignored. If warn is zero (the default) warnings are stored until the top–level function returns. If fewer than 10 warnings were signalled they will be printed otherwise a message saying how many were signalled. An object called last.warning is created and can be printed through the function warnings. If warn is one, warnings are printed as they occur. If warn is two or larger all warnings are turned into errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not reproducible:

```
R> cor(rep(1,7), rep(1,7))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In cor(rep(1, 7), rep(1, 7)) : the standard deviation is zero
R>
```

Make sure you have the most recent version, make sure you don't have random stuff floating in your session etc.